# Find what the given sum is equal to

Tags: calculus

I am given the following sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{1}{2^{n+2}(n+2)}}$$
How do I find what is it equal to? It sort of looks like a logarithm, but not exactly, so how do I proceed to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this look better to you?
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}$$

Comment: Or is $$-x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$ even better?

Comment: How did you reach $$-x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$? Can you post an explanation on how you reached it?

Comment: I changed the variable in Jean-Claude's formula :-)

Comment: How so? I'm a bit slow at understanding...

Comment: For example if I had $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac1{2^{n+4}(n+4)}}$$  how would I proceed

Comment: @Sartr See my HINT posted herein.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, but still don't get it :)

Comment: @Sartr I've edited to add a "Spoiler Alert."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\int_0^x t^{n+1}\,dt=\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2} \tag 1$$

Now, sum both sides over $n$ and let $x=1/2$.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> For $|x|<1$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}$ converges.  So, for $|x|<1$, we sum both sides of $(1)$ to obtain $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x t^{n+1}\,dt \tag 2$$For all $x_0<1$ and $|x|\le x_0$, the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$ allows us to interchange the summation and the integration in $(2)$.  Proceeding, we find that $$\begin{align}\\\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2}}{n+2}&=\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{n+1}\,dt\\\\&=\int_0^x \frac{t}{1-t}\,dt\\\\&=-x-\log(1-x)\tag 3\\\end{align}$$ Letting $x=1/2$ in $(3)$ yields the coveted result $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+2)2^{n+2}}=\log(2)-\frac12$$And we are done!

Comment: How would you integrate *that* sum of GP?

Comment: You can interchange the order of integration and the series.  The series is a geometric one $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{n+1}$.  Then, integrate the result.

Comment: Woah, that makes sense, it's a shame they missed to teach us that. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure and pleased this was helpful.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

If you know that

$$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k$$

you can set $x=\frac12$ and deduce the first term. Then

$$\frac12+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{2^kk}=\log2.$$